# Unable to select input text box element in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get the data from the input text box and update without `id` and `name`. The following is the HTML code for that input tag. Here `id`, `name` and `value` changes from element to element.

```
<input id="rgrdSearchResult_ctl00_ctl06_dtpLocalDateTime_dateInput" name="rgrdSearchResult$ctl00$ctl06$dtpLocalDateTime$dateInput" class="riTextBox riEnabled" value="03/06/2017 17:00" type="text">
```

I tried the following code.

```
public String getDateTime(WebDriver driver){
    List<WebElement> lis = driver.findElements(By.className("riEnabled"));
    WebElement ele = lis.get(1);
    return ele.getAttribute("value");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the first one? Try lis.get(0)

Comment: No, Second one. First one is the empty input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is that `By.className` is looking for is the whole text `"riTextBox riEnabled"` (including the space character). It would probably work if you changed your selector to `By.className("riTextBox riEnabled")`, though I doubt that's what you want.

Try using `By.cssSelector` instead. There are multiple ways of doing it, for example:

```
By.cssSelector("input[contains(@class, 'riEnabled')]")

By.cssSelector("input[class*='riEnabled']")
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution for that. I used "cssSelector" with "riTextBox".

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider accepting it. Glad you got it to work!